# How to assign value to class properties?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to set values of `email` and `password` variables to `userreg` which is in the type of `UserRegister` which should take `email and password` arguments.

Errors: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'UserRegister'.`, `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'password'.`

```
export class UserRegister {
    email: string = '';
    password: string = '';
    }

let email = 'test@test.com';
let password = 'testpass';
let userreg: UserRegister = email, password; 


private doRegister(): void {
    this.Authentication.register(userreg)
    .catch((message: string) => this.formError = message);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value assignation should be

```
const uEmail = 'test@test.com';
const uPassword = 'testpass';
const userreg: UserRegister = {email: uEmail, password: uPassword };
```